# Is it safe to convert String to String[] by split(\0)?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

For giving a string (which does not contain "\0") of type String to function as parameter, which must be of type String[], I convert String to String[] in such way:

```
string.split("\0")
```

What do you think, is it safe enough?

Will it always work as expected (for any String without "\0")?

Comment: Why don't you just directly create a new array ?

Comment: string.split("\0") is not valid as I don't think it means what you think it means. See the answer by @Slackow for a better idea.

Answer (score 6):

is there a reason against doing

`new String[]{string}`?

because that would be more efficient than that method and more readable.

edit: I'd also like to add that split can have a second parameter on max size for the array, so if you put some regex in there you can just put `1` as the second param and guarantee that it will not actually do any splitting, but there is no reason to do that over the above method.

Comment: Reason: If, instead of new String[]{}, split("\0") is used, then PMD does not give the message "Avoid instantiating new objects inside loops" .

Comment: interesting, well if you do decide to stick with that, just use split("\0", 1) because then even if you have \0 you will have no chance of it splitting, is there no way to suppress an inspection? like how in IntelliJ you can just put a comment above the line and say

//noinspection all